# Send data with button from php to java script

Tags: php, javascript, string

Hi i want to send data from php code to java script and java script code send themes to another php file like below:

```
<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" id="edit" onclick="sendToEdit(<?php echo $row['pID'] ?>,<?php echo $row['phID']?>,<?php echo $testHistoryDate ?>,<?php echo (string)$type ?>);"  />
```

when i debug with firebug i see php code make true values in the php area but when send themes to java script can't send `<?php echo $testHistoryDate ?>,<?php echo (string)$type ?>);` true values and send another date for testHistoryDate and true value for `(string)$type` but fire bug make below error:

```
Phibrinozhen is not defined
```

[Break On This Error]

sendToEdit(9004, 119002, 1997, Phibrinozhen);
in the above code 1997 isn't true value true value is:

```
onclick="sendToEdit(9004,119002,2010-10-03,Phibrinozhen);"
```

that php make but java script 
java script code

```
function sendToEdit(pID,phID,thDate,type)
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is occurring because you trying to pass string literals without telling JavaScript they are strings. You need to escape at least your final two parameters with quotes: `'2010-10-0', 'Phibrinozhen'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit" id="edit" onclick="sendToEdit('<?php echo $row['pID'] ?>','<?php echo $row['phID']?>','<?php echo $testHistoryDate ?>','<?php echo (string)$type ?>');"  />
```